# What to do when you find slow running query?

Tags: sql-server, performance, c#, query-performance

I have two databases. One with 10.000 rows and one with 10 million rows.

I have a load test and I am running it towards a rest api endpoint. This endpoint does a query to database and average response time is 9 seconds. Same query on small DB runs on average 200ms. I am trying to understand why are the amount of rows causing this problem.

I used Azure Query Performance Insight to find the slowest query. This is all I have access at the moment.

The main thing is that database DTU is on 100% when this is running, but option is not to scale up the DB, but to tune what I have now and see what causes the issue.

I never did performance before, but I read on google that I should check execution plan. Since I am using load tests, does this execution plan means the app that does queries with DB(code) and then see the query itself?

I have a query, but I am clueless on how to continue to resolve this issue? segregate query per table (there are a lot of joins for this query - Entity Framework is used in code).

What can I actually do as only a developer, and no DBA experience from before with only Azure Insights?

Any good tutorials to learn this, or is this just DBA experience?

Table example:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.ContentItems
( 
    Id int IDENTITY(10000,1) NOT NULL
    , SiteId int NOT NULL
    , ContentType int NOT NULL
    , Title nvarchar(500) NOT NULL
    , Name nvarchar(100) NULL
    , UrlTitle nvarchar(100) NOT NULL
    , Promo nvarchar(max) NOT NULL
    , PromoImageUrl nvarchar(500) NULL
    , Body nvarchar(max) NOT NULL
    , BodyImageUrl nvarchar(500) NULL
    , More nvarchar(max) NULL
    , AdSentence nvarchar(max) NULL
    , CreatedDate datetime NOT NULL
    , UpdateDate datetime NULL
    , PublishDate datetime NOT NULL
    , AuthorId int NULL
    , AuthorDisplayName nvarchar(50) NULL
    , ContentCategoryId int NULL
    , IsActive bit NOT NULL
    , IsLive bit NOT NULL
    , IsFeatured bit NOT NULL
    , PostCode nvarchar(9) NULL
    , VideoEmbedCode nvarchar(max) NULL
    , MainImageUrl nvarchar(500) NULL
    , UserGui nvarchar(100) NULL
    , UserName nvarchar(100) NULL
    , RowVersion timestamp NOT NULL
    , TopicTagId int NULL
    , TurnOffAdverts bit NULL
    , IsLegacy bit NOT NULL
    , ReferenceId int NULL
    , ShowDashboardPromo bit NULL
    , CanonicalUrl nvarchar(max) NULL
    , IsIncludeProductPromo bit NOT NULL
    , IsVisible bit NOT NULL
    ,  CONSTRAINT PK_ContentItems 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
        ( Id ASC )
        WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF
            , STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF
            , IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF
            , ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON
            , ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
        )
)
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.ContentItems 
ADD CONSTRAINT DF_ContentItems_CreatedDate 
DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR CreatedDate
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.ContentItems 
ADD CONSTRAINT DF_ContentItems_PublishDate  
DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR PublishDate
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.ContentItems 
ADD CONSTRAINT DF_ContentItems_IsActive  
DEFAULT ((1)) FOR IsActive 
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.ContentItems 
ADD CONSTRAINT DF_ContentItems_IsLive 
DEFAULT ((0)) FOR IsLive 
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.ContentItems 
ADD CONSTRAINT DF_ContentItems_IsFeatured  
DEFAULT ((0)) FOR IsFeatured 
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.ContentItems 
ADD DEFAULT ((0)) FOR IsLegacy 
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.ContentItems 
ADD CONSTRAINT DF_ContentItems_IsIncludeProductPromo  
DEFAULT ((0)) FOR IsIncludeProductPromo 
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.ContentItems 
ADD CONSTRAINT DF_ContentItems_IsVisible_Default  
DEFAULT ((1)) FOR IsVisible 
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.ContentItems  
WITH CHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ContentItems_TopicTags 
FOREIGN KEY (TopicTagId) 
REFERENCES dbo.TopicTags (Id) 
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.ContentItems 
CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_ContentItems_TopicTags 
GO
```

Comment: Yes this is SQL Server database. I added DDL

Comment: Format your code by selecting it then pressing CTRL-K

Comment: Thanks for including the DDL - are there really no indexes on this table?  You may want to look at Brent Ozar's excellent topics on performance tuning at https://www.brentozar.com/sql/sql-server-performance-tuning/

Comment: Can you add an example of a problematic query?

Comment: Query plans are xml/graphical representation of how the db carried out your query, after it's been processed by the optimizer. Removes a lot of guesswork. Basics plans in SSMS: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J69zLvoh2oI. Do you have perms to execute the query and connect via SSMS?

Comment: you can do lot as developer and more than DBA.DBA role come much later. Definetly your example table is not normalized and contain lot of nvarchar field.Anyway since queries are written EF,so first read few article on writing optimize EF .Or EF generate sql query,you can paste the problematic query here.